# google Api Client not connected error

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and i used Google Places Autocomplete but whenever i am running the project it throws an error of Google Api Client not connected.My Main_Activity.java file is as under

```
package com.example.sunny.myapplication2;

/**
 * Created by sunny on 4/3/2016.
 */
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class enter_your_locality extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

    private EditText mAutocompleteView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
    ImageView delete;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        setContentView(R.layout.enter_your_locality);
        mAutocompleteView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);

        delete=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cross);

        mAutoCompleteAdapter =  new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.search_view_adapter,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);

        mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }else if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag,Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
                        /*
                             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                         */

                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if(places.getCount()==1){
                                    //Do the things here on Click.....
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
        Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
        Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
        Toast.makeText(this, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==delete){
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
            Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.v("Google API","Dis-Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I searched for the related articles but in vain . Can anyone please guide me.
And my logcat shows as under

```
04-03 11:32:28.231 11863-11863/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-03 11:32:28.343 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
04-03 11:32:28.343 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 553: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-03 11:32:28.343 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
04-03 11:32:28.407 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
04-03 11:32:28.411 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
04-03 11:32:28.431 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
04-03 11:32:28.431 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
04-03 11:32:28.595 11863-11890/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18896: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18900: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
04-03 11:32:28.599 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-03 11:32:28.627 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 13% free 3022K/3460K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
04-03 11:32:28.647 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-03 11:32:28.647 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 616: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-03 11:32:28.647 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-03 11:32:28.647 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-03 11:32:28.667 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 638: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-03 11:32:28.683 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-03 11:32:28.867 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-03 11:32:28.891 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-03 11:32:28.899 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-03 11:32:28.951 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-03 11:32:28.951 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-03 11:32:28.951 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-03 11:32:28.971 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-03 11:32:28.971 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-03 11:32:28.971 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 11:32:38.731 11863-11890/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-03 11:32:40.175 11863-11883/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 254K, 11% free 3276K/3644K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-03 11:32:40.211 11863-12070/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
04-03 11:32:40.311 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-03 11:32:40.315 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 V/Google API Callback: Connection Failed
04-03 11:32:40.315 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 V/Error Code: 1
04-03 11:37:39.547 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 282K, 11% free 3504K/3896K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
04-03 11:37:39.551 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/Google Places Auto Complete: Google API not connected
04-03 11:37:39.979 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/Google Places Auto Complete: Google API not connected
04-03 11:37:40.087 11863-11863/com.example.sunny.myapplication2 E/Google Places Auto Complete: Google API not connected
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

Follow [the google guide](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app#set-up-your-project) to setup your project.

Comment: I tried the method suggested by you but it still shows the same error